# Kotlin: How to inherit from RxJava Subscriber

Tags: android, rx-java, kotlin

I want my NewsListSubscriber to inherit from an RxJava Subscriber which use a generic type but I get a "Type mismatch" error when I call the UseCase execute method. I read many times the generics page from the Kotlin documentation but I can't find the solution.

Here is my UseCase:

```
abstract class UseCase(private val threadExecutor: IThreadExecutor,
                       private val postExecutionThread: IPostExecutionThread) {

    private var subscription = Subscriptions.empty()

    fun execute(UseCaseSubscriber: rx.Subscriber<Any>) {
        subscription = buildUseCaseObservable()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(threadExecutor))
                .observeOn(postExecutionThread.getScheduler())
                .subscribe(UseCaseSubscriber)
    }

    protected abstract fun buildUseCaseObservable(): Observable<out Any>

    fun unsubscribe() {
        if (!subscription.isUnsubscribed) {
            subscription.unsubscribe()
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how I call it:

```
override fun loadNewsList() {
    getNewsListInteractor.execute(NewsListSubscriber())
}

private inner class NewsListSubscriber : rx.Subscriber<List<NewsModel>>() {
    override fun onCompleted() {// TODO}

    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {// TODO}

    override fun onNext(t: List<NewsModel>) {// TODO}
}
```

The error is

> "Type mismatch. Required: rx.Subscriber. Found: Presenters.NewsListPresenter.NewsListSubscriber"

in the "execute(NewsListSubscriber())" line. I tried playing with the "in" and "out" keywords but I still have the same error.

Comment: Is Subscriber class in the method signature the same as the rx.Subscriber superclass in the inner class?  Just checking, can't tell for sure here without seeing the imports.

Comment: Yes it is, I updated my code to use rx.Subscriber in both case.

Comment: `Subscriber<Any>` is the equivalent of `Subscriber` which is not compatible with any more specific notations.
The solution is to introduce a generic type that is used for both `execute()` input and `buildUsecase` output.

Comment: When you tried "out" and "in", you were doing it on `Subscriber<Any>`, right? I would think that would fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is actually a better way to solve this problem. I ran into the same issue and a type cast inside every derived subscriber class was not an option.

Just update the abstract UseCase class with an generic type parameter.

```
abstract class UseCase<T>(private val threadExecutor: IThreadExecutor,
                   private val postExecutionThread: IPostExecutionThread) {

    private var subscription = Subscriptions.empty()

    fun execute(UseCaseSubscriber: rx.Subscriber<T>) {
        subscription = buildUseCaseObservable()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.from(threadExecutor))
                .observeOn(postExecutionThread.getScheduler())
                .subscribe(UseCaseSubscriber)
    }

    protected abstract fun buildUseCaseObservable(): Observable<T>

    fun unsubscribe() {
        if (!subscription.isUnsubscribed) {
            subscription.unsubscribe()
        }
    }
}
```

When you declare your derived UseCase classes, use your concrete type for the generic parameter when calling the super class.

```
class ConcreteUseCase(val threadExecutor: IThreadExecutor,
               val postExecutionThread: IPostExecutionThread)
               : UseCase<ConcreteType>(threadExecutor, postExecutionThread)
```

Doing so, you can use typed Subscribers in your `execute` call.

```
getNewsListInteractor.execute(NewsListSubscriber())

...

private inner class NewsListSubscriber : rx.Subscriber<List<NewsModel() {
    override fun onCompleted() {// TODO}

    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {// TODO}

    override fun onNext(t: List<NewsModel>) {// TODO}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution that is pretty simple actually: my NewsListSubscriber class has to extends from rx.Subscriber<Any> instead of rx.Subscriber<MyWantedClass>. It means I need to cast the received objects to the wanted type.

```
private inner class NewsListSubscriber : DefaultSubscriber<Any>() {

    override fun onCompleted() {}

    override fun onError(e: Throwable) {}

    override fun onNext(t: Any?) {
        val newsList = t as List<News>
        ...
    }
}
```

In Java the cast is done in background but in Kotlin we need to do it ourself.

I also removed all "in" or "out" keywords in my UseCase class.